# IronPython define utf-16 character in string

Tags: python, windows, unicode, ironpython, utf-16

I want to define utf-16 (LE) characters by their number. 
[An example  is 'LINEAR B SYLLABLE B028 I'.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10001/index.htm)

When I escape this character by u'\U00010001' I receive u'\u0001'.
Really,

```
>>> u'\U00010001' == u'\u0001'
True
```

If I use unichr() I get errors too:

```
>>> unichr(0x10001)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 65536 is not in required range
```

How can I define utf-16 characters in my Python app?

IronPython 2.7

Comment: That's a "SMP character", not a "UTF-16 character".

Comment: Works as expected on Linux. Probably because Windows uses [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), not full Unicode. 0x10000 and 0x10001 codepoints do not belong to BMP.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: That would be true if Windows only supported UCS-2. It supports UTF-16 though, which *should* allow this code to work (depending on what .NET supports, of course).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You are probably right. The absence of _windows_ tag made me read this question )

Comment: works as expected (unicodedata.name(u'\U00010001') returns 'LINEAR B SYLLABLE B038 E') in cpython on win.

Comment: Smells buggy! Do you get a working surrogate pair from `'\xf0\x90\x80\x81'.decode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a named literal:
    print "\N{LINEAR B SYLLABLE B038 E}"

If the other methods work on cpython but not ironpython please open an ironpython issue with a minimal test case.